# Python 3 Documentation - Function Annotation

Tags: python, documentation

I use the following format to document my Python code:

```
def my_function(param: str) -> dict:
   some code
```

I can't figure out how to document a function passed to another function.

For example:

```
def my_function(my_other_function: ???) -> dict:
    some code
```

**How do I make a function annotation?**

Comment: You are looking for "Function Annotations"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable

Comment: That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **First Thoughts:** "Everything in python is an object"

I couldn't find anything in the docs, but as `everything in python is an object` i would shoot for `object`.

```
def my_function(my_other_function: object) -> dict:
    some code
```

To proof it:

```
if isinstance(my_function, my_function, object):
    print("yes")
    >yes
```

Anyhow, this might not be too explicit, therefore:

> **Seconds thoughts:** Using proper type hints

Based on what `COLDSPEED` commented, a more explicit type hint would be using `typing`

```
import typing
def my_function(my_other_function:typing.Callable):->dict:
    pass
```

> "The only way that annotations take on meaning is when they are interpreted by third-party libraries". Which means, for your source-code itself, it doesn't change anything. Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna use one of the two solutions.